# Is it possible to integrate native libraries/ Mobile SDKs with Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I am developing a Flutter application and I need to implement a Payment SDK which is available in my country. They have Android SDK and iOS SDK, then Javascript, etc SDKs, but not Flutter.

My question is, is it possible for us to implement native SDKs in Flutter? In this case, I will have to integrate both Android and iOS SDKs. Is this is supported, then How can I do this?

Comment: I have found [this](https://blog.solutelabs.com/integrating-third-party-native-sdks-in-flutter-df418829dcf7)

Comment: Flutter documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a platform channel that will call a method that passes the handling to the native side. On the native side, you can use your PaymentSDK specific code. This way you will be able to use native code from SDK depending upon your platform but your flutter code base won't have to worry about platform, at it will be calling the same platform channel method.

Check out here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: i gotta try flutter. seems promising

Comment: It is very promising since they also planning to support Web+Desktop(windows & mac) soon. Flutter-web is in Alpha already.